# tableView offset isn't changed on device rotation

Tags: swift, uikit

I animate the buttons in the tableView. The animation depends on the offset of the tableView. If offset > 385 for portrait and > 280 for landscape some of the buttons are hidden and others show up. Opposite happen when I scroll other direction. So far everything works smoothly.

The bug happends when I rotate the screen. In some cases just after rotation tableView doesn't update the offset and wrong buttons are shown on the screen. The offset updates when I start scrolling again and everything works like it should.

How do I get the hold of the new offset value straight after rotation? I want the animation to have correct behaviour straight after rotation not only when user scrolls the table.

Cheers

I tried to catch the tableView offset value in viewDidLayoutSubviews() and viewWillTransition() but it always the old value before ratation. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you try viewWillLayoutSubviews()? There are only two methods for changing from vertical to horizontal position.
viewWillLayoutSubviews() - before rotating
viewDidLayoutSubviews() - after rotating